# How to Install multiple font in android device manually

Tags: android, fonts

**Q : I want to install multiple fonts in my rooted android device is it possible ?**

**What i did till now is as follows :**

1. I rooted my device
2. I was able to copy my fonts to the /system/fonts directory

   - using the adb shell command
3. I rebooted the device in order to get the effect of the font in my IME keboard application

**Result :** I was not able to get the font working.

**Font used are :**

1. Shruti for gujarati
2. Devanagari for hindi

Answer (score 2):

Copy the .ttf file to the sd card and click on the file in file manager to install it. It should work.